# Ruby / Rails - produce path to uploaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I'm trying to get my "path to an uploaded archive.zip"

in my model:

```
def path_to_upload
  "#{self.folder.path}"
end
```

gives me:

```
/Users/jweber/Sites/Proofer_v2/public/assets/415/Archive.zip
```

but what I want is,

```
/Users/jweber/Sites/Proofer_v2/public/assets/415/
```

and I've produced it with:

```
def path_to_upload
  "#{self.folder.path.split("/").reverse.drop(1).reverse.join("/")}/"
end
```

but that looks crappy, Do you know a "beautiful" way to return the desired output?  I'd even settle for less than hideous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
File.dirname(self.folder.path) + '/'
#=> "/Users/jweber/Sites/Proofer_v2/public/assets/415/"
```